# What is r in Django urls.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

The basic urls.py got statements like this,

```
(r'^home/$', homeview),
```

What is actually the `r` here?
What is the use of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a prefix for [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) (escape sequences are ignored) which is useful for sane regular expressions.

Excerpt from the docs:

> When an `r'` or `R'` prefix is present, backslashes are still used to quote the following character, but all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `'n'`

So the `r'\n'` is equivalent of the `'\\n'`.